# limit is not working in query cakephp 3

Tags: pagination, cakephp-3.0

I am using the following query to show list of data, but here limit is not working.

```
$query = $this->Bookings->find('all')
    ->where(['Bookings.user_id' => $id])
    ->contain(['Services'])
    ->limit(10)
    ->orderDesc('booking_date');

$this->set('bookings', $this->paginate($query));
$this->set('_serialize', ['bookings']);
```

but, I am not getting the list of 10 data in each page.

Comment: try put `->orderDesc('booking_date')->limit(10)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is better to use the `$paginate` property and then use the `maxLimit`

See: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#limit-the-maximum-number-of-rows-per-page